# IOS Memory Leak Analysis

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I added the following code to my app:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
```

Before adding this code, I got no leaks when running the xCode Instruments Leaks tool. With this code added, I get a leak:
Leaked Object: _NSCFString,
Address: 0x5572e0,
Size: 32 bytes,
Responsible Library: AudioToolBox,
Responsible Frame: AudioSessionGetProperty.

The code lines were plucked from IOS Library sample code. Any advice on what is wrong and what I need to do to fix it?

thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no leaks in the code you posted. There *may* be leaks in Apple frameworks, though, but you cannot do anything about them. Most likely, it's a false positive reported by the Leaks instrument.

Comment: Leaks only reports false positives in rare circumstances (e.g., if you store an encoded pointer rather than the raw pointer). However, I've only seen this happen with Carbon on OS X (I think it was in HIToolbox.framework), never on iOS. On the other hand, leaks does fail to report things that really are leaks, especially on 32-bit systems.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I haven't had to deal with memory leaks much, so I don't know much about them. My app seems to work fine for long periods of time, but I was a little worried that Apple may give me problems with approval if it was showing a leak.

Comment: I actually found out that the first call to `[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]` causes this. Subsequent calls do not add to the leaks. No idea if it's an Apple bug or Instruments acting up though.